# Marathon-lb not returning keep-alive headers

Tags: marathon, dcos

We're in the process of migrating a microservices application to dcos. The current version of the application use nginx as a reverse proxy. In moving to dcos, we'd like to replace nginx with marathon-lb. This is working well, with one exception. Nginx returns the expected `Connection:keep-alive` http header, but marathon-lb does not.

We have not changed the default configuration of marathon-lb in any way, and as far as I can tell haproxy has the expected defaults. Specifically, the `http-server-close` option. Here is a snippet from the config.

```
defaults
  load-server-state-from-file global
  log               global
  retries                   3
  backlog               10000
  maxconn               10000
  timeout connect          3s
  timeout client          30s
  timeout server          30s
  timeout tunnel        3600s
  timeout http-keep-alive  1s
  timeout http-request    15s
  timeout queue           30s
  timeout tarpit          60s
  option            dontlognull
  option            http-server-close
  option            redispatch
```

My services have labels with the following format:

```
  "labels": {
    "HAPROXY_0_PATH": "-i /alerts",
    "HAPROXY_0_HTTP_BACKEND_PROXYPASS_PATH": "/alerts",
    "HAPROXY_0_VHOST": "foo.bar.com",
    "HAPROXY_GROUP": "external"
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try use `option http-keep-alive` and `option prefer-last-server`.

See : [Haproxy + netty: Way to prevent exceptions on connection reset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21550337/haproxy-netty-way-to-prevent-exceptions-on-connection-reset/40005338#40005338)

You can override default configuration by `HAPROXY_GLOBAL_DEFAULT_OPTIONS`.

See : https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon-lb#haproxy-global-default-options